# C++/CLIからCランタイムライブラリとの依存関係を無くす

Tags: c++, c++-cli

現在、C++/CLIを使ったアプリケーションを作成しています。

C++/CLIでDLLを作成し(CライクにDllexport構文を使っての関数公開です)
そのDLLをネイティブCとWin32で作成したアプリケーションが呼び出しています。

呼び出し側は、MTオプションでCランタイムと依存関係が削除できますが、C++/CLIの場合、MTオプションは適応できないので、なんとかしてCランタイムとの依存関係を削除したいのです。

何か良い方法があれば、ご教授ください。

Comment: どういう点から「原理的に無理」なのかを回答としてご自身で投稿されたほうが，後にこのサイトを見た人の助けになると思います．

Comment: @パリン 自己解決した場合には自身で回答を記載してチェックマークを付けて頂けると、他の方に本質問がクローズしている事が分かりますので、対応宜しくお願いします。

Comment: http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/1676/%E3%82%BF%E3%82%A4%E3%83%88%E3%83%AB%E3%81%AB-%E3%82%AF%E3%83%AD%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BA-%E3%81%A8%E5%90%AB%E3%81%BE%E3%82%8C%E3%81%9F%E8%B3%AA%E5%95%8F%E3%81%AE%E5%AF%BE%E5%87%A6

Answer (score 1):

> 調査の結果、原理的に無理ということが分かりました。
>   策として、ＣランタイムDLLをアプリと同時に配布することで解決させました。
>
> [質問者ご自身の回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/revisions/4410/4)より

Answer (score 0):

探されているのは [方法: CRT ライブラリ DLL との依存関係を削除して部分信頼アプリケーションを作成する](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/ms235238.aspx) でしょうか？

追記： 実行時に指摘されるmsvc**r**NN.dllと、記事で触れているmsvc**m**NN.dllは別物ですね（NNは対応するVisualC++のバージョン）。MSDNに[/clrオプションとCRTライブラリへの静的リンクは共存不可](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/abx4dbyh%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)とある通り、msvcr100.dllへの依存を切ることは不可能な気がします。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
ご紹介いただいたMSDNの記事は当方も確認したのですが、その手順通りに行い、実機で動かしてみたところ、msvcr100.dllが必要、とのメッセージが出現します。
私の設定の仕方の問題なのか、それとも当該記事が私の求めている内容では無いのでしょうか…？